# How to connect Thomson TG585v7 wifi router to Android tethering wifi hotspot?

Tags: router, wireless-networking, android, tethering

I'm trying to connect my PC to the internet through the use of my Thomson wifi router and Android 3G connection. More details follow.

I have an HTC Desire running Android 2.2 Froyo on which I have set up a wifi hotspot to tether my 3G connection.

My laptop has a wifi card and I have no problem connecting to the internet via the wifi hotspot (both from Ubuntu and Windows XP).

Unfortunately my PC has no wifi connection, only an ethernet connection to my Thomson TG585v7 DSL Modem + Wifi router. I am trying to connect the PC to the internet by going over ethernet to the Thomson router and then from there via wifi to the Android tethered hotspot and then via 3G to the net.

However so far all my attempts have been unsuccessful. I am connected to the Thomson TG585v7 as Administrator and have tried to configure the "Home Network" section, enabling WDS in various configurations. I tried to set the SSID, Channel number, connection method (WEP and WPA) and WEP key all to be the same on the router as well as the phone but still no luck. The TG585v7 does pick up my phone's access point but I haven't been able to get a link set up. I should also point up that I got the TG585v7 from the Be There ISP in the UK and the firmware seems to be customised to them.

I have picked up that I might need to look at Bridge Mode or WDS but am not familiar with either and the articles I have found so far haven't helped.

My PC is a Ubuntu 9/Windows Vista 64 dual-boot and I'm happy to use either to make the connection but I think the issue is more with the router.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!